# How do I programatically change the form template for an existing list

Tags: 2010, development, custom-list, custom-form

I've started creating all my SP lists in-code, because I find it to be way more reliable than using schemas. I can ensure lists on-the-fly, change existing fields during development, etc. And if someone breaks my list by deleting a field or something, I can just re-ensure the list with my code, and everything is fixed.

But what I haven't been able to figure out how to do yet is set up customized form templates. For example, in a schema, you'd normally do something like this:

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" Template="ListTemplateName" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" Template="ListTemplateName" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" Template="ListTemplateName" />
</Forms>
```

I want to do that same thing, except I want to do it on a list that already exists (we're working on version two of a web app). I want customized forms for the New and Edit forms for a list.

I can't seem to be able to edit anything spList.Forms. Everything is a getter, not a setter. How do I define my own list in code, as I would have done in a schema with the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to your question in this blog. Author of this blog says what you are asking is possible. In his words

> You have created a custom list through the browser and now you just
>   need to change the forms displayed by default or you just want to do
>   that programmatically without editing the list content type
>   definition!?! That’s possible, just keep reading!

http://achrafsp.wordpress.com/tag/programmatically-provisioning-list-custom-forms/

Comment: I'm marking this correct with some extra info ...
I wanted to use a template, not a custom aspx page. YOu do this with:
`SPContentType ct = list.ContentTypes["Item"];
ct.NewFormTemplateName = "CustomTemplateNameWhichYouPutInControlTemplates";
ct.Update();`